Excel - Issue with Index+Match Formula
I would appreciate if I could your help with below formula, I just don't see what am I doing wrong here:
Example Table < Click here

Issue Description:
It works for on first Column but it doesn't work for other column, it finds the first match and return correct result but later it doesn't work, also strange behavior that I don't understand as showed in "G" Column, it works but only if Match array continues going down, locking the same range doesn't work.
This works, but now lookup range is not correct < click here
Questions:
What can I do to make this work and keep Match Array locked on my table?
Formula: =INDEX($E$19:$E$34,MATCH($C4,$C$16:$C$31,0),MATCH(G$3,$D$19:$D$34,0))
